# Reason for inconsistency in specific gravity of calcium choride added to water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, density

I am seeing a significant change in specific gravity of products upon addition of $\ce{CaCl2}$ to water. The mass and volume of what goes in doesn't match my total specific gravity of what comes out. I am curious as to why that is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say, "of products", do you really mean "of the solution"? If so:

The solvent mass and the solute mass add up to the mass of the solution.

But solvent volume and solute volume often *don't* add up to the volume of the solution. This is because the forces between molecules in the solution are different from the forces between molecules in the pure solute and the pure solvent.

In your solution, the calcium ions and chloride ions attract water molecules around them. The water molecules are packed more tightly than they would be if the ions weren't there. That can increase the density of the solution relative to the total volume of the unmixed solvent and solute. Another effect is that the ions in solution are packed *less* tightly than they are in solid $\rm CaCl_2$.

You can see which effect wins by dumping some calcium chloride into a volumetric flask. Fill the flask up to the mark with water, and then mix until all the calcium chloride dissolves. The solution probably doesn't quite come up to the mark anymore, because the calcium and chloride ions have drawn the water molecules in around themselves, making the solution denser than it would be otherwise.

**More detail than you may want below:**

The volume of the solution $V$ is given by the following equation:

$$V = n_1 \overline{V}_1 + n_1 \overline{V}_2$$

where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are moles of calcium chloride and moles of water in the solution, and $\overline{V}_1$ and $\overline{V}_2$ are the [partial molar volumes](http://www2.stetson.edu/~wgrubbs/datadriven/fchen/bartender/partialmolarvolumechen.html) of the calcium chloride and the water.

These partial molar volumes are actually derivatives of the volume of the solution with respect to moles of calcium chloride ($\overline{V}_1 = \partial V/\partial n_1$) and with respect to water ($\overline{V}_2 = \partial V/\partial n_2$). They are related to each other (when one rises, the other falls) and they vary with the composition and temperature of the solution in a rather complicated way.

Comment: This ushered me forth in a direction that finally made sense. I ended up finding this website, http://www.chem.latech.edu/~ramu/cmen522/homework/hw06_04a.pdf, that further explained the dynamic as well. I gathered what was necessary to be done, but wasn't quite sure how to apply it. I am currently a chemist for the oil field and am trying to find an accurate representation of percent water and CaCl2, as well as the correct specific gravity of the complete solution. Given a 10.5 Mud weight (10.5 lb/gal), I have struggled to find volumes necessary to add and partial volume actually present.

Comment: Further explained - I applied the formula designated V /cm3 = 1001.97 + 30.2207m1/2 − 36.7889m + 37.0838m3/2 − 5.7447m2 for the corrected solution volume and was really close to the correct "loss" of volume from the packing you described. The two following formulas for partial volumes −36.7889 + 15.1104m−1/2 + 55.6257m1/2 − 11.4894m (for CaCl2) and 18.048 + 0.2722m1/2 − 0.3341m3/2 + 0.1035m2 (for water), don't add up to the total solution loss. I am a bit baffled as to why this is the case. Granted my physical chemistry knowledge is a bit dated, I would assume my excel document is correct.